# Definite integral and Riemann sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$ \int_0^1 x^2 dx $

n is the number of pieces to cut into

For $ (x_i - x_{i-1}) = \frac {0+1}{n} $ and $ x_i = \frac in $

Using the right Riemann sum: $ \Sigma_{i=1}^n f(x_i)*(x_i - x_{i-1}) $

$ \int_0^1 x^2 dx = lim_{n\to\infty} \Sigma_{i=1}^n \frac {i^2}{n^2} \frac in   $

My question is : when we are taking the definite integral from 0 to 1, why is the Riemann sum formula summing up from 1 to n?

It could be silly, but it's eating me.

Comment: Because the $n+1$ points $x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ determine $n$ subintervals. So there are $n$ rectangles. One could equally well sum from $0$ to $n-1$ and use $(x_{i+1}-x_i)$, of course.

Comment: Ok.. So for whatever interval the definite integral is taking, the number of rectangles that we cut into will be counted from 1 to n..

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Look, you cut $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals, the difference between left Riemann integral and right Riemann integral is that on every subinterval, we choose the the function value of left point and right point to be the approximation of the function value on whole such interval, so $\lim_{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\frac{i}{n})(x_i-x_{i-1}) $ and $ \sum_{i=1}^n f(\frac{i-1}{n})(x_i-x_{i_1})= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(\frac{i}{n})(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ are both the approximation of the Riemann integral of $f$ on $[0,1]$.